# PowerShell script not executing bcp command properly

Tags: powershell, bcp

I have the following part of a function that is driving me crazy. As you can see, I am generating a path and file name to bulk copy table data to. When I run this within the PowerShell script I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe:  unknown option 1
usage: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe
```

However, when I copy the output string I get from the Write-host command and paste it into the command prompt I can execute it just fine. What gives?

```
ForEach($table in $db.Tables | where {$_.IsSystemObject -eq $false})
{

        $fullName = "$db.$table"

        If($scriptTables -contains $fullName)
        {
              $fullFilePath = (pwd).path + "\$db.$table" + ".dat"
              $copyExecString = "$db.$table out `"$fullFilePath`" -E -N -Sserver1\instance -Uxyz -Pxyz > Output.txt"
              & bcp "$copyExecString" #Invoke-Expression "bcp $copyExecString"
              Write-host "bcp $copyExecString"                      
        }

}
```

Example of output:

```
bcp [DB].[dbo].[Table] out "C:\Development\ScriptDemoData\[DB].[dbo].[Table].dat" -E -N -Sserver1\instance -Uxyz -Pxyz > Output.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to expand a string into various properties.

You could however just pass them in directly.

```
.\bcp.exe $db.$table out "$fullFilePath" -E -N -Sserver1\instance -Uxyz -Pxyz > Output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with executing legacy commands in Powershell sometimes the invoke operator (&) will work and sometimes it won't especially if there a lot arguments as is the case with bcp.exe. Another way to execute legacy applications is to use start-process. I've reworked your code and tested the following successfully.

```
try {add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" -EA Stop}
catch {add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo"}

try {add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" -EA Stop; $smoVersion = 10}
catch {add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo"; $smoVersion = 9}

$ServerInstance = "$env:computername\sql1"
$Database = 'AdventureWorks'
$server = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $ServerInstance
$db = $server.Databases[$Database]
$scriptTables = ,'[AdventureWorks].[Sales].[StoreContact]'

ForEach($table in $db.Tables | where {$_.IsSystemObject -eq $false})
{

        $fullName = "$db.$table"

        If($scriptTables -contains $fullName)
        {
              $fullFilePath = (pwd).path + "\$db.$table" + ".dat"
              start-process -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardOutput output.txt -FilePath bcp -ArgumentList @"
$db.$table out "$fullFilePath" -E -N -S$ServerInstance -T
"@
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's  because of the quotes, I suspect.

`bcp "$copyexecstring"` will enclose your parameters in double quotes.

To simplify, I would put the $bcp inside the string, then just use `Invoke-Expression`:

```
$copyExecString = "$db.$table out `"$fullFilePath`" -E -N -Sserver1\instance -Uxyz -Pxyz > Output.txt"
$copyexecstring = "bcp $copyexecstring"
$return = (Invoke-expression $copyexecstring) | Out-string
```

Comment: `"` cause variables to be expanded. `'` do not. I do not believe either is passed on to the executing function (they are stripped by the OS)